# C++ array initializer. Using enum type

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, initializer

```
class ARouter {
    enum directions {north, neast, east, seast, south, swest, west, nwest};
    static directions gon[] = {north, neast, nwest, east, west, seast, swest, south};
};
```

Hi, does anyone know what is the matter with the above code?

I am getting 2 errors for the second line from VC++2008Ex:

> error C2059: syntax error : '{'
>
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those lines.  You probably have a syntax error further up the file, which is causing the compiler to become confused.  Or perhaps you're defining the variable somewhere invalid, like inside a class body.

Comment: Post more code, it compiles on my end.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it AFAIK; your code works fine in g++ 4.

Comment: You sure? I just bracketed it off into a little class for completeness. I haven't really changed anything else to break it. I'll take the lines out and try again. brb.

Comment: Back. Nope, those lines are definitely breaking it.

Comment: That's very strange.  I just copy-and-pasted the source into a file "c.cpp", then ran "g++ -c c.cpp", and got two errors: `a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before ‘{’ token` and `invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘ARouter::directions []’`.  That's with g++ 4.5.2, 4.1.2, and 4.2.1, 3.0.4, 2.8.1, and a few others (the errors vary with older versions).  Solaris "CC" also complains.  How are the rest of you getting it to compile without errors?  (No, the original question hasn't been edited.)

Comment: Keith Thompson, that's an impressive number of gcc versions you have co-installed there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define a variable inside a class like that.

It needs to be something like:

```
class ARouter {
    enum directions {north, neast, east, seast, south, swest, west, nwest};
    static directions gon[];
};

ARouter::directions ARouter::gon[] = {north, neast, nwest, east, west, seast, swest, south};
```

The *declaration* goes in the class body; the *definition* lives outside.  Note that you'd typically put the class body in a header, and the definition in a source file.

Comment: The pseudonym "class variable" mislead me in this case.